# GraphQL Tutorial - Expected undefined to be a GraphQL schema

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-js

I try to learn GraphQL. I created a project and I did what [this page](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/) says.

**Install**

```
   npm init
   npm install graphql --save
```

**Server.js**

```
var { graphql, buildSchema } = require('graphql');

// Construct a schema, using GraphQL schema language
var schema = buildSchema(`
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`);

// The root provides a resolver function for each API endpoint
var root = {
  hello: () => {
    return 'Hello world!';
  },
};

// Run the GraphQL query '{ hello }' and print out the response
graphql(schema, '{ hello }', root).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

**Run**

```
node server.js
```

This returns me an error.

```
    throw new Error(
          ^
Error: Expected undefined to be a GraphQL schema.
    at assertSchema (C:\Users\BK\Projects\Test\graphql-test\node_modules\graphql\type\schema.js:35:11)
    at validateSchema (C:\Users\BK\Projects\Test\graphql-test\node_modules\graphql\type\validate.js:34:28)
    at graphqlImpl (C:\Users\BK\Projects\Test\graphql-test\node_modules\graphql\graphql.js:52:64)
    at C:\Users\BK\Projects\Test\graphql-test\node_modules\graphql\graphql.js:21:43
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at graphql (C:\Users\BK\Projects\Test\graphql-test\node_modules\graphql\graphql.js:21:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\BK\Projects\Test\graphql-test\server.js:18:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
```

**Versions**

- graphql: "^16.0.1"
- node : v16.13.0

Comment: Sadly I think this toturial misses the point of GraphQL :/
Move to the next page it gets more realistic. But in a beginner level aim to work less with `root` value and more with `resolver`s this is closer to how you will really build schemas in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I was following the same tutorial and I had the same problem. After going to the next page, as U Rogel suggested, I had the following problem:

```
Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer graphql@"^14.7.0 || ^15.3.0" from express-graphql@0.12.0
npm ERR! node_modules/express-graphql
```

So, I decided to modify my graphql version in the `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-graphql": "^0.12.0",
    "graphql": "^14.7.0"
}
```

Then I ran `npm install`,  went back to the first page and it worked!
I think the problem is that version 16+ does not work with the basic examples.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I no longer follow this site. Instead, I attend [Apollo GraphQL](https://www.apollographql.com/). I recommend it to you too, it is very understandable and clear.